# How can I download a .exe file from a given URL?

Tags: wine, executable

I would like to download, then install a .exe file from a URL via the command line via wget or curl.  Specifically MS Build Tools 2015 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159) .

I understand that I cannot install a .exe through Ubuntu, and must install wine to do so.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine (Please let me know if anyone has any other recommendations.)

How would I go about downloading the .exe file from the given URL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks! - I should have mentioned that Ubuntu is running on my build server, so therefore I cannot directly via the URL via a web browser.

Comment: I found that `wget` worked, thanks to a Answer that was added to the question, and then removed before I could accept it.

Comment: Another tip: you can install [`lynx`](https://lynx.browser.org/) (`apt install lynx`). That's _the_ text-mode browser. Quite cool thing. It doesn't show pictures and such (afaik), but I sometimes install it on servers so I can at least google a bit, even without a GUI.

Comment: Thanks @PerlDuck - that sounds super useful, so I'll give that a go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will be redirected to exe file. You can download it as usual:

```
wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/E/D/EEDF18A8-4AED-4CE0-BEBE-70A83094FC5A/BuildTools_Full.exe
```

Or simply open link [from your question](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159) with your web-browser.